# All of a sudden NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I had to do some development for an old project that uses Spring with annotations.

I got it from SVN (no changes since the last deploy), generated a war using Gradle as usual, deploying it in a Tomcat with the same version as before, and try to run with the same Java version. All as always, except the version of Eclipse used.

The problem is that I am getting `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` for each field that defines a class that extends an abstract class. It's like if Spring, for some reason cannot determine which class it should use, even it is specified in the signature of the method:

```
@Autowired
@Override
protected void setEntityDao(ListboxItemDao entityDao) {...}
```

Where `ListboxItemDao` extends `GenericDao`

And I am getting this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [com.section.generic.dao.GenericEntityDao] is defined:
expected single matching bean but found 32: listboxItemDao, anotherDao1, anotherDao2...
```

I see that I can fix it by adding a `@Qualifier("listboxItemDao")` however I don't understand why this was working before without this `@Qualifier`. It is very annoying that now, because of a small change I have to add this `@Qualifier` to all the services...

What could it be that now I require this `@Qualifier` when all the environment is the same?

Comment: Please share your applicationContxt.xml too

Comment: Hmm... there is no applicationContext.xml.

Comment: This is all I can find regarding application context: @Service
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        AppContext.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    }
}

Comment: in web.xml I have: <!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: Is the `build.gradle` also same ?

Comment: Yes, it has not been changed.